# Android - Navigation Bar replace my Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation-bar

The problem is in the title, I use a Bottom Navigation View/Bar, it works fine on smartphone without virtual Navigation Bar :

[On my Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge without Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYHgo.jpg)

And with a virtual NavBar, the Bottom Navigation View disappear :

[On my Huawei with virtual Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxfOm.jpg)

I tried to remove the Navigation Bar and force the application to go on Fullscreen and the Bottom Navigation View/Bar appeared.

It's why I think that the Navigation Bottom Bar is overrided by the Navigation Bar from the smartphone.

I want my Navigation Bottom Bar to be above the virtual Navigation Bar!
Help me to fix this bug please.

EDIT :
Here is the layout of this activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_fond_opacite"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigationAvis"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <com.luseen.luseenbottomnavigation.BottomNavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationAvis"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:bnv_active_color="@color/vraiment_pro_vert"
            app:itemBackground="@color/vraiment_pro_fond_gris"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/vraiment_pro_fond_gris"
            app:bnv_active_text_size="@dimen/bottom_navigation_text_size_active"
            app:bnv_colored_background="true"
            app:bnv_inactive_text_size="@dimen/bottom_navigation_text_size_inactive"
            app:bnv_with_text="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: could you share your layout file of this issue

Comment: @AmitBhandari I added the layout to the main post

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `RelativeLayout` height to `match_parent` as shown below.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it ! It was a problem with something in my code that was blocking the UI, unfortunately, sorry :)